# Hibernate context not configured with multiple WAR's

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

After an upgrade to Spring 4.0.6 and Hibernate 4.3.5 I have the fallowing problem when i try to deploy the application (I have 2 WAR's with a similar core dependency which contains the configuration for the Hibernate) :

- When I deploy a single WAR file everything seams fine, no exceptions are thrown
- When I deploy both WAR files I get the fallowing error:

  org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

-

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.buildCurrentSessionContext(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1513) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) [spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) [spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:424) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(PropertyPathFactoryBean.java:186) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1540) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1418) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:788) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:541) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:387) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:362) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1002) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:646) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:962) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1603) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_39]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not introspect Hibernate JtaPlatform for SpringJtaSessionContext
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.<init>(SpringSessionContext.java:65) ~[spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException: Could not locate Bitronix TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(BitronixJtaPlatform.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:209) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:194) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.<init>(SpringSessionContext.java:59) ~[spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(BitronixJtaPlatform.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: bitronix.tm.utils.InitializationException: cannot open disk journal
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.<init>(BitronixTransactionManager.java:98) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager(TransactionManagerServices.java:75) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read(FileDispatcher.java:28) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:144) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at bitronix.tm.journal.TransactionLogHeader.<init>(TransactionLogHeader.java:101) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at bitronix.tm.journal.TransactionLogAppender.<init>(TransactionLogAppender.java:70) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at bitronix.tm.journal.DiskJournal.open(DiskJournal.java:157) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.<init>(BitronixTransactionManager.java:85) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
```

I have tried with :

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class"\>thread</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class"\>managed</prop>
```

Comment: if you deploy the 2nd war first, do you still get the problem? Might it be that the 2nd war is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is from Bitronix Transaction Manager because is instanced twice , for each WAR file . Is posbile to use other TransactionManger ?

Comment: If i deploy any WAR's like this ( which have some common module responsible for persistence) will throw exception .

Comment: You should be using `jta` for the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property as that is what bitronix is a JTA implementation. Also how are you configuring Bitronix? Judging by the stacktrace a single instancce is used which leads to locking problems on the transaction journal.

Comment: in past we used Bitonix ony for connection pool , but now it is used for transactions and all , i think a solution is to define in tomcat. But i want to use "org. springframework.orm.hibernate4. HibernateTransactionManager" and I do not now how to do that . Thanks also for editing the content!

Comment: The solution I found is described here : [Bitronix in Tomcat](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Tomcat2x#Tomcat2x-Step4ConfiguretransactionmanageranddatasourcesinitializationinyourMETA-INFcontextxml) but I do not want to define properties related with datasource in tomcat because profiles will not work with that.